# how build parent child relationship in pyspark or python?

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, graphframes

I have numbers like key,value`(1,2),(3,4),(5,6) ,(7,8),(9,10),(2,11),(4,12),(6,13),(8,14),(14,19)`

my input is `(1,2),(3,4),(5,6) ,(7,8),(9,10),(2,11),(4,12),(6,13),(8,14)`

here i need to create relation 1 --> 2  and  `2--> 11` my final output is(`1,11)`..i.e. if you consider first tuple key is 1 and 2 value again one of the other given tuple  2 is key and 11 is value.i.e.parent and child and grand child relation i want my output is like `(parent,grand child)`

```
my final output should be: (1,11),(3,12),(5,13),(7,19),(9,10)
```

Suppose i have a  dataframe like below:

```
key   value
 1     2
 3     4
 5     6
 7     8
 9     10
 2     11
 4     12
 6     13
 8     14
14     19
19     23
13     17
```

my excepted output is new df:

```
key  value
1    11
3    12
5    17
7    19
9    10
```

how to implement in python /pyspark?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: How is the <sql> language involved? Are those numbers stored in a table?

Comment: @jarlh Spark can use direct SQL instruction. But I updated the tags to `spark-sql` more appropriate.

Comment: So you want a SQL answer? Or a Python answer?

Comment: @DirtyBit ,I tried using tuples but not working

Comment: @RKC please display a proper input dataframe with schema and expected output

Comment: @Steven i have changed question.please find above

Comment: @jarlh, ,if you consider my dataframe  is table1 with columns key ,value  how to achive thie

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but something like this should do the trick:

```
s = [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6),(7,8),(9,10),(2,11),(4,12),(6,13),(8,14)]

for parent, child in s:
    g_child = [x[1] for x in s if x[0] == child]
    if g_child:
        print((parent, g_child[0]))
    else:
        print((parent, child))
        break
```

OUTPUT:

```
(1, 11)
(3, 12)
(5, 13)
(7, 14)
(9, 10)
```

Comment: thanks for quick reply it is working as per my requirement,but now only 2 levels suppose if i have 3/4 levels then suggest me how can i achieve .(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)  my output is (1,4)